# System.NullReferenceException while taking screenshots with selenium.WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

There is some problem. I'm using webdriver with C#. Here is the code

```
 ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
 Screenshot screenshot = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
 screenshot.SaveAsFile("c:/Image_23.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Then it throws System.NullReferenceException for the line:

```
 Screenshot screenshot = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
```

Where am I mistaken?

Comment: screenshotDriver object is null in your case. driver object is not  casting in ITakesScreenshot.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this library, but the `ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot;` line needs to be changed. Depending on how the library works, it may be something like `ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = new ITakesScreenShot(driver);`, but it could be something different depending on the library.

Comment: What type of driver is it? You can try directly casting it, and see what happens: `var screenshotDriver = (ITakesScreenshot)driver;`.....

Comment: I am having this same issue now. Did you ever find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The `System.NullReferenceException` happens when you leave an object null. In your code `Screenshot = screenshot = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();` is left null, make sure you are putting a value into it before you try to compile